# Displaying minimum rows in DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

DataGridView is connected to the DB by using bindingSource.
I want to fill DataGridView with empty rows, not grey color, even when the DB record is few.
If you see the attached screen capture, you will see what I want to do.

[image]

Can anybody give me some advice?

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to achieve? Is it that you just don't like the look of the grey area? Or do you want the empty rows available for users to edit and add more data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818947/fill-the-datagridview-with-empty-rows

Comment: I want to add empty rows in case of no data